# R extract numbers from within brackets

Tags: regex, r

I have the following string

```
/blast/?about=P23415[29-457]
```

I want to get both numbers in a df so i can access them separately i.e. df[1]

where I am trying to extract the numbers within the square brackets. I have tried using

```
gsub('.+\\[([0-9]+)\\].+?$', '\\1', mystring)
```

however this is returning the entire string.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: it won't works because there is an `-` symbol inside that brackets. Did you want `29-457`?

Comment: I would ideally like both numbers that I can access separately, or if not just the first number. i'll update my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the numbers inside the `[]` brackets without `-`, the try the below

```
gsub('.+\\[([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\\].*$', '\\1\\2', mystring)
```

And even more better regex,

```
.+\[([0-9]+)(?:-([0-9]+))?\].*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tM5nN4/3)

Comment: HI avinash - I would like them separately - have edited post to explain this. my bad - sorry. but this answer does pull out the numbers as one string.

Comment: see the first command where the `\1` prints the numbers before `-` and group 2 contains the numbers which was just after to `-`

Answer (score 5):

Use something like this:

```
regmatches(subject, gregexpr("\\[\\K[^\\]]+(?=\\])", subject, perl=TRUE));
```

- `\[` matches the opening brace
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns
- `[^\]]+` matches all chars that are not a closing brace (this is the match)
- The lookahead `(?=\])` asserts that what follows is a closing brace

**Option 2: digits-digits**

If you know that the content inside the brace is always of the form `digits-digits`, you can make the regex more specific:

```
regmatches(subject, gregexpr("\\[\\K\\d+-\\d+(?=\\])", subject, perl=TRUE));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(str1, perl('(?<=\\[|-)[0-9]+(?=\\]|-?)'))[[1]] 
#[1] "29"  "457"
```